# Webmatrix paging - inclusion of array causing problems?

Tags: sql, razor, pagination, webmatrix

```
var pageSize = 6; 
var totalPages = 0; 
var count = 0;
var page = UrlData[0].IsInt() ? UrlData[0].AsInt() : 1;
var offset = (page -1) * pageSize;

string selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM PropertyInfo ";

//some (if) statements which append various (where) clauses to the query

selectQueryString += "ORDER BY NumBedrooms DESC OFFSET @0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS  ONLY;";

string[] argArray = argList.ToArray();
```

So then i try and piece it all together by defining the values of @0 and @1

```
queryResults = db.Query(selectQueryString, argArray, offset, pageSize);
```

But this gives me the error "No mapping exists from object type System.String[] to a known managed provider native type."

any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that you can combine passing an array and parameter list together - either switch all parameters into the array, or switch them all to use @0, @1 style ordinals.

Also, as a side note, the line:

```
var page = UrlData[0].IsInt() ? UrlData[0].AsInt() : 1;
```

Can be simplified using the default parameter of `AsInt()` with:

```
var page = UrlData[0].AsInt(1);
```

Comment: gotcha. I think passing them all into the array will be easiest. Leave me with it and i'll let you know how i get on. Cheers